# File encryption with AES-256-CBC vs Chunk encryption

Tags: security, encryption, tcp, aes, cbc-mode

First of all this is my first question here, I hope I can get you a clear idea of the problem and also help others that may face similar challenges! Also the title of the question was the shortest TL;DR I could get :-)

So in order to give you a little context I'm basically designing a protocol that requires a **synchronous and ordered** file transmission from a server (implemented in Node.js) to a device, over **TCP**. Streaming the file is not an option, so each file chunk is encapsulated in a message that has other non-encrypted fields, which are out of scope of this question.

One of the requirements is that the file contents can not be sent in plain text, so an encryption scheme had to be chosen, in this case I opter for the **AES-256-CBC**, assume for the purpose of this question that the algorithm can't be changed.

Due to device constraints (RAM ~10KB), it's required to split the file (**<5 MB**) into chunks, that will be then sent to the device according to the mentioned protocol, following a **send / [ack|repeat]** scheme. On reception, the device is able to store the chunk on disk.

So my main question here is that in the backend I have to choose between:

- **Encrypting the complete file and then split it into chunks**

  -> On reception device would append each chunk in a file and then decrypt it when all chunks were received.

### **vs**

- **Dividing the file into chunks and then encrypt each of them.**

  -> Requires the sending of the **Initialization Vector** (IV) used on each chunk encryption in order to decrypt it.

  -> On chunk reception the device would have to decrypt the chunk or store each of them with the respective IV and then decrypt them after receiving the last chunk.

**The goal here is to understand what security issues arise from each approach and also an overhead comparison between them.**

PS: I also have an integrity validation scheme but is out of the question's ambit.

Comment: I've deleted my answer for now because it is no longer relevant given your new information.  I'll post a new answer when I can.

Comment: Ok, thank's for your input and understanding! @LukeJoshuaPark

Comment: You could use a stream encryption mode and wrap the entire socket stream in encryption that way. This is better because there are no blocks and no padding anymore to deal with. .NET does not have a stream mode built in but popular crypto libraries support that. You can keep using AES.

Comment: The goal is not to encrypt all message data but just some of it's fields, that's why the encrypted socket approach is not valid in this case @usr

Comment: Can you clarify again why streaming is not an option and why you think you need an ACK? I'm not really understanding what you mean exactly by "chunks" either. Do you have one chunk of encrypted data followed by a chunk of unencrypted data and so and and so forth?

Comment: Just before going further, what about your AES Key ? Is the key already on the device ? Or do you have to transfert the key before/after sending the file ? For the same device, only one file will be transferred or is it possible to transfert many files at different time ? If yes, are you going to use the same AES key ?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark streaming is not an option because I need to send some more data alongside the chunk forming a packet that will be sent to the device. The chunk is just a piece of data from the file. The packet contains several fields, one for the encrypted chunk, and other ones that are out of scope in this question. So basically the number of packets sent will be equal to the number of file chunks (if no problem occurs). I hope I have managed to clarify a little better.

Comment: I feel like the things that you think are out of scope will make your question easier to understand.  At this point, I feel like I can't answer the question because I can't fully understand what you need to achieve.

Comment: @gduh The key agreement process is out of scope in this question, but you can assume that is already on the device in the beginning of the transfer process and it is an unique key per session. There is going to be only one file transfer per session, so at the end of the transfer the "session" will be closed. But I would like to address the main point about the two approaches at the end of the question.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I'm sorry and I understand that it may be difficult to address this topic, the problem is that if we start discussing all the key agreement process, the session handling, etc, this question would become very broad and not focused on the point of split file and encrypt each chunk vs encrypt file and then divide into chunks, the rest of the information given was just to give some context, maybe I should've only posted the last part of the question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer to your question, beyond the question of the key AES in my other comment, I think the best way is the second solution. But in your case I will add a HAMC for every chunk. So :

- Divide the file into chunks
- Generate an IV for every chunks
- Encrypt the chunks with the corresponding IV and the AES Key
- Add an HMAC (using a different AES key than for the encryption, so you need 2 AES keys) compute on the IV+Cipher_text for each chunk (it's important to use the encrypted chunk and not the clear-chunk)
- Send your chunks
- Receive your chunks on the device.
- Check the HMAC for every chunks (in that way it will confirm the chunk is not corrupted and well authenticated)
- decrypt the chunks with 1st key and the corresponding IV
- Added all chunk to get your original file.

The second is more secure since you can control all your chunks before to decrypt them.

I mean that if you encrypt chunk by chunk and adding a HMAC, when you receive a chunk on your device, first you check the HMAC, if it's ok, you can decrypt the chunk. In that way, if someone is on your network and try to corrupt or anything else a chunk, the HMAC can authenticated the origin and the content of the encrypted chunk.

While this is not possible with your first option. If someone try to corrupt a chunk during the transfert, well, at best your can not decrypt your global-chunk, at worst it could give some information to the hacker about the encryption system. It will just a piece of the puzzle for the attacker. It will not be sufficient, he will need a lot of more tries to expect to decrypt himself a chunk, but it's a risk.

Comment: Thank's for you answer as it addresses the main point discussed on the question, can you please just clarify what was the rationale to opt for the second choice?

Comment: I have modified directly my answer since my message was too long for a simple comment.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as I find it more complete since it goes straight to the point and also provides an implementation approach.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there are parts of this question that are missing that would help give a better overview of the problem, but at face value, with the information provided, you'd likely be better off with the **second** option.

With the first option, you limit the malleability of your scheme due to the fact that, for a given chunk, it is unlikely that you can decrypt the content on the fly due to your use of CBC mode.  While this may not be a requirement of your scheme currently, it *could* be in future.

With the second option, you pass your data around as independent blobs.  You can encrypt and decrypt these blobs at will and combine them when necessary.

There are likely further pros/cons for each option, but the details of your scheme that you have provided don't provide an opportunity to find out what they are.  I suggest you err on the side of caution.  I understand the device you are working on has very strict requirements that make traditional cryptography a lost luxury, but designing and implementing your own cryptosystem is incredibly difficult to do correctly, **especially** under such strict requirements.  It already sounds like your scheme does not provide forward secrecy, which means any other issues would likely be disastrous if push comes to shove.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Luke! You are right, I'm working with strict requirements that's why it's hard to design this, and more importantly to justify each decision made, that was my goal here, to back my decision as much as possible with the community feedback. It would be awesome if I could just for instance use HTTPs, but it is what it is :D Addressing your concern about PFS, I have a unique key per file transfer "session" so that issue is covered.